# SQL Server Management Studio connection defaults to 'master' when selecting a database-specific object

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio, if I right-click on an object inside a specific database and choose "Select top 1000 rows ..", the database connection for the query window always opens on 'master' while the table name is fully qualified as [database].[dbo].[table]. This makes it impossible to jump in and tweak out this query and insert joins, etc., to the statement without also fully-qualifying everything I add, or add a USE statement, or select the database from the drop-down menu.

Is there a setting or something that will make query windows open with a database connection of the selected object browser's database rather than connect to 'master', and not fully qualify the object's database in the query text? I realize that I can register my SQL connection to default to my database, but we actually go through multiple new databases every week--in a given month I will have touched tens of databases--so it would be difficult to manage multiple database registrations. I would rather it if SSMS just connected to the specified database. Possible and straightforward?

Comment: I'm not sure who voted to close (as off-topic), but I disagree. The FAQ clearly outlines that questions about programming or the tools used to do so are on-topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such setting for the `SELECT TOP` command, but you may be able to do this by changing the default database for your login. This is tedious if you're doing this often for various databases (much like changing the registrations, as I just noticed you already outlined).

Instead of using `SELECT TOP 1000` (which in addition to not putting you in the right database context, also puts a `TOP` in that I assume you're just going to remove as well), you should right-click the table and choose `Script Table as` > `SELECT to` > `New Query Window`. This puts the context in the right DB, adds a `USE` command, doesn't have a `TOP` and doesn't database-prefix the table name.

Comment: Marked as 'accepted answer' because "Script Table as" is a suitable workaround, not because of the first part of the answer. Like I explained in the question details, there are far too many databases to be fussing with a user-level setting over and over.

Comment: I tested the Script Table As.  While it puts you in the correct database, it still writes the query fully qualified.  I just did a Select To for a btnet table, and it queried [btnet].[dbo].[bug_posts].

Comment: @stimpy77 yep, just wanted to be sure I laid out all possible workarounds. I caught that sentence in your question *after* I posted (and added a comment to that effect in parentheses).

Comment: @sumo good point.. snap .. validated as well, still fully-qualified DB name. aargh

Comment: @Sumo what version of Management Studio are you using? This is working correctly for me in Denali CTP3 (also seems to be working for stimpy). I did try this in 2008 R2 and you're right, it does still use the database prefix there. But at least the database context is correct, so added tables don't also need the prefix.

Comment: meh .. well I had to retract the "accepted answer" only because the database name is still fully qualified which is verbose, but at least it connects to the database so I'm torn on this .. EDIT: oh if MSFT fixed it in the future release, nevermind, I'll accept *sigh*

Comment: @stimpy77 I don't think there's going to be a "perfect" fix for you unless they fix the tool. But I think your hassle is more about the use / drop-down command and new tables you add, and less about the existing single prefix. 2 out of 3 ain't bad...

Comment: @stimpy77 Might I suggest [RedGate SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/), then?  Other than that, this answer is probably the closest you'll get if they don't correct the feature.

Comment: @Aaron 2008 R2 (10.50.2500.0)

Comment: And of course another workaround is to install the Denali CTP3 version of Management Studio and use the script option there. As I explained, in Denali that option opens with the right database context, without TOP, and without the database prefix. And as I already mentioned, this is a limitation in the current version of the tool, not a limitation in the knowledge of the folks trying to help you.

Comment: @Aaron By chance, have they fixed intellisense support for synonyms?  :)

Comment: @Sumo no, IntelliSense does not follow synonyms. This connect item says it is fixed, but I do not see the correct behavior in 2008 R2 SP1 or in Denali CTP3. Did you vote? http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/331633/

Comment: @Sumo I re-opened the item. It either isn't fixed or desperately needs some context from Microsoft about where to find the alleged fix.

Answer (score 17):

If you are going in via Win Auth, are in a group, are using SA or some other userid, or are in a situation where changing your login is not really the solution, AND if all you wish to do is default to a database in the query editor:

- In an existing open query editor, right-click, select Connection, Change Connection.
- Click the Options button to expand the options.
- In the Connection Properties tab, select the database you wish to connect to.

SSMS will remember your selection for that server. You may have to repeat for other servers, but it does remedy having a default database other than master.

Comment: Hadn't realised this. My new connection was openning a different db by default than my supposed default database. What I did note however was that after changing the db in the dialog I needed to restart SSMS in order for the change to take effect. Cheers - been bugging me for weeks :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want query window connects to some database by default, in SSMS go to the Security -> Logins, select the login that you use to connect to this server, and loock at the properties window. In page 'general' change the default database from 'master' to database you want to connect.

Comment: Won't that force the same database to be the same all the time?  It's the same issue as the master database, just now it's a user database.

Comment: Thanks. That would be a permanent change, though, until I change it again. SSMS should know how to wire up my connection based on the table I right-clicked. I think this behavior changed since SQL 2005.

Comment: Not sure about that.  I just right-clicked a table, clicked Script Table As > Select To > New Query Editor Window and it put me in the correct database in the Available Databases dropdown, and opened the query in the query window.

Comment: @Sumo, that is a different query generator than the "Select Top 1000 Rows..". However, it is a workable workaround, which Aaron Bertrand proposed as an answer.

Comment: Yes @Sumo, but it doesn't work the same way with SELECT TOP n ROWS.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put a `USE [database name]` at the top of the query window prior to executing a query.  You do not need to fully qualify the database names if you do this.  If you generate any scripts and version control them, this is a good practice to put at the top anyway. It at least prevents executing the script erroneously against the wrong database (say creation of a stored procedure).

```
USE MySpecialDatabase
GO

SELECT * FROM MySpecialTable
```

Comment: No, because the table is still fully-qualified with a database name and I don't want to have to support that as I make my edits on top of the USE statement. I already click on the drop-down menu and find the database, it's too much hassle.

Comment: You do not need to qualify your queries with the database name if you use a USE statement.

Comment: "You do not need to qualify your queries with the database name if you use a USE statement" .. tell that to Microsoft who created the query generator. My question relates to right-clicking and choosing the "Select Top 1000 Rows ..", from which a query is generated and a fully-qualified object name is generated. I know I don't need to fully-qualify them if I "USE" my DB, that is the problem.

Comment: @sumo, the point is, the db prefix IS there when using SELECT TOP n ROWS. Stimpy doesn't want it there.

Comment: Thank you, that threw me off.  The other script commands seem to do the same.  DOH!