# Add Use Command when Selecting Top 1000 from Database Object

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been searching for this answer and haven't had any luck. My problem is that whenever I
`Select top 1000 from tblX` it defaults the database to Master and I have to manually change to the correct `DB`. I know on my VDM at work when doing this, it adds a `Use` command which specifies the correct database and gives me a connection instantly. I've read that you can change the default database, but I will be switching back and forth between many databases. So I want my connection defaulted to which ever database the selected table is from.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Management Studio?  The default behavior is to schema qualify the table in the code generated statements `database.dbo.table`.  Also check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806245/sql-server-schema-and-default-schema).

Comment: If I got it correctly you mean that you want to auto-select the database of the table which you are generating code for. I don't think there is a native way, but maybe you can workaround using the "Set As  Active Connection" of the [SSMSBoost add-on](http://www.ssmsboost.com). Another way could be to edit or create a SQL Server template from the Template Explorer in your SQL Server Management Studio. You can simply add the USE command with a template (however you need to add the parameter value manually).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [db name].dbo.[table name]

Comment: Yes, but after selecting from a database and a new query window opens it defaults to master, I want it to default to whatever db the selected table is from. This gets done by the Use command being generated while selecting top * 1000 from table

Comment: Looks like there is already another post with same question which suggests some setting changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072575/sql-server-management-studio-connection-defaults-to-master-when-selecting-a-da

Comment: i saw that question too it wasnt what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could always change the default schema for you user. But this is not my preffered approach. You should always use two part name naming or in your case 3 part according to the 70-461 Training kit.

[image: Changing Default Schema]